# How to achieve dynamic custom template using ngx-formly

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I am using `ngx-formly`, and try to introduce a custom template, which is for view only. When the template is static, it is ok, but if I try to introduce some angular operation, it doesn't work. See [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-asawaa). Any suggestions?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(model)">
      <formly-form [model]="model" [fields]="fields">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </formly-form>
    </form>

    {{ model|json }}
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model = {};
  name = "John";
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {template: `<div>{{name}}</div>`}, // <-- I expected to see John, but I saw {{name}}
    {
      key: 'name',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Field 1',
        placeholder: 'Formly is terrific!',
      },
    },
  ];

  submit(model) {
    console.log(model);
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any specific reason to use ngx-formly?

Comment: @AjayOjha, I already had some code written using ngx-formly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question into github and got the right answer, please check [this](https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly/issues/1302) for more details.

- First approach, check code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hd17hb)

  - It doesn't support obervable
- Seconde approach, check code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-asawaa)

  - It support observable, but have to upgrade `ngx-formly` to `v5.beta` at this moment I compose this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Set up the module

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [ 
     BrowserModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     FormlyModule.forRoot({
       types: [
        { name: 'customInput', component: FormlyFieldInput },
       ]
     }),
   ],
   declarations: [ AppComponent, FormlyFieldInput ],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Set up custom component and listen to keyup

```
@Component({
  selector: 'formly-field-input',
  template: `
     <div>{{this.model.profilePictureNotEditable}}</div>
     <input type="text" [formControl]="formControl"  [formlyAttributes]="field">`,
})
export class FormlyFieldInput extends FieldType implements OnInit {
    val;
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.key);
      console.log(this.model)
    }

}
```

Set up the form correctly in app.component

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(model)">
     <formly-form [model]="model" [fields]="fields">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </formly-form>
     </form>

    {{ model|json }}
    `,
 })
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model = {profilePictureNotEditable: 'John'};

  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
  {
   fieldGroup: [
   {
    key: 'name',
    type: 'customInput',
    templateOptions: {
    label: 'Field 1',
    type: 'text',
    placeholder: 'Formly is terrific!',
  },
 }]
}];

 submit(model) {
   console.log(model);
   this.model.profilePictureNotEditable = 'this will be the profile picture!'
   }
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-ydrfss
Hope this will help you!!

Comment: thanks for your detailed solution. custom field rocks. It is a good solution for the scenario some static field is related to one certain field. But if it is not,it will be wired, like when I am updating a user, I want to show the photo (not updatable) in the form.

Comment: The power of ngx-formly!  You can use the model to update any customField !!https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-ydrfss

Comment: thanks, but I am thinking [this approach](https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly/issues/1302) is more appropriate in my case.  :)

Comment: That approach you foollow in github, is doing  model = { name: 'test' }; that is exactly what I suggest you to do (use the model anywhere), on top of a custom field (the item 0 in fields array).  And this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hd17hb  has 2 custom fields, instead of one.... flavours to render 2 things instead of one, but essentially you need to use the model as per my suggestion. Good luck :)

Comment: I think they are different, your approach has to bind to an input, but that approach is standalone.

Answer (score 0):

```
{template: `<div>{{name}}</div>`}
```

should be:

```
{template: `<div>${name}</div>`}
```

see [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)